# changing state and persisting it via checking from backend

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a page with the list of N number of products.
And each product has a button which performs toggle operation on a click that is on the click it changes database value to 1 and 0. 1 says stock available and 0 for unavailable.
How can I do it without using local storage to persist the state even after page reload

Comment: Isn't your app fetching the products from your backend when rendering the first time? After a page reload your app should reflect the current state of your backend db.

Comment: yes it is fetching from the backend @trixn

Comment: So where exactly is the problem? After a page reload it should display the most recent state of your backend db. Are you posting the updates to your backend?

Comment: problem is  that state  changes after the page reload

Comment: Yeah on button click the backend value toggles

Comment: So you want your front-end to subscribe to backend changes so that if one person toggles one product availability all other people using the app too can immediately see the change?

Comment: yeah. exacatly.

Comment: Okay that is a completely different problem from what you initially described. It's is not about persisting state but pushing state from the backend to the frontend. How should local storage help you solving that? You would need to either poll the backend endpoint frequently or use e.g. websockets to be able to push updates to the client with the client requesting it explicitly. Polling is the easier to implement but it creates some network overhead.

Comment: OK and in UI 
I should just be using like 
`value === 1  ?  stockavailable  :  Unavailable`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem. Now you are asking something completely irrelevant to the problem you described in your question. This is just how you would display a label given a binary encoded value. If the problem is about your code please share it in your question.